# Undefined variable error, though it's defined in function

Tags: function, python-3.x, undefined

```
def append_customer(file_variable, fields):
"""
-------------------------------------------------------
Appends a customer record to a sequential file.
-------------------------------------------------------
Preconditions:
    file_variable - the file to search (file)
    fields - data to append to the file (list)
Postconditions:
    The data in fields are appended to file_variable.
-------------------------------------------------------
"""
if os.path.exists(file_variable) == True:
    file = open(file_variable, "w", encoding="utf-8")
    file.seek(0)
    print("{0}".format(fields), file=file_variable)
file.close()
return
```

This is a function i wrote to append data to a file, the only error being that apparently "file_variable is undefined"... even though it's clearly defined by the function. I have no clue as to why this error is occurring.

Comment: Is this your indentation?

Comment: Show us where you call the function. [mcve] please.

Answer (score 0):

This seems closer to what you want:

```
def append_customer(file_variable, fields):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Appends a customer record to a sequential file.
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Preconditions:
        file_variable - the file to search (file)
        fields - data to append to the file (list)
    Postconditions:
        The data in fields are appended to file_variable.
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    if os.path.exists(file_variable):
        with open(file_variable, "a", encoding="utf-8") as fobj:
            fobj.write("{0}\n".format(fields))
```

You need to indent the function body.

If you want to open an existing file for appending you need to use `'a'` which means "open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists". The `with` statement opens the file and closes it when leaving the indentation.

Comment: Yep, these are all good suggestions, although it's hard to say if any one of them will fix the OP's error message. Since it's not clear what's causing it in the first place.